# get first available time in a day that is not conflicting with an array of hours

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to get first available time either hour or hour and a half (will explain what I mean by hour and a half in an example) in a given day when I have other non-available hours in javascript.

Example #1:

> If the current time is 8:45am and the unavailable hours are between "7:00am and 8:00am" + "10:00am and 11:00am" the first available time would be 9:00am.

Example#2:

> If the current time is 1:35pm and the unavailable hours are between "2:00pm and 3:00pm" then the first available time is 3:30pm

Example #3:

> If the current time is 11:00pm and the unavailable hours are between "11:30pm and 1:00pm" + "1:30pm and 2:00pm" then the first available time is 2:30pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a function `getFirstAvailableTime()` to search for the desired time.

We'd start at `now` plus one minute, then iterate through each timeslot, checking each one to see if it overlaps any of our `unavailable` timeslots.

If it does not overlap an unavailable timeslot we return it as the first available time.

```js
function getFirstAvailableTime(now, unavailable, timeSlotSize = 30) {
    // Start at the first available timeslot _after_ now. 
    const start = Math.ceil((minutes(now) + 1) / timeSlotSize) * timeSlotSize;
    for (let min = start; min < 1440; min += timeSlotSize) {
        if (!unavailable.find(({ start, end }) => (min >= minutes(start) && min <= minutes(end)))) {
            return { hour: Math.floor(min / 60), minute: min % 60 };
        }
    }
}

function minutes( { hour, minute }) {
    return hour * 60 + minute;
}

function formatTime({ hour, minute }) { 
    return [hour, minute].map(n => (n + '').padStart(2, '0')).join(':');
}

function formatSpan({ start, end }) { 
    return [formatTime(start), formatTime(end)].join(' - ');
}

const inputs = [{ now: { hour: 8, minute: 45 }, unavailable: [{ start: { hour: 7, minute: 0}, end: { hour: 8, minute: 0} } ] },{ now: { hour: 13, minute: 35 }, unavailable: [{ start: { hour: 14, minute: 0}, end: { hour: 15, minute: 0} } ] },{ now: { hour: 11, minute: 0 }, unavailable: [{ start: { hour: 11, minute: 30}, end: { hour: 13, minute: 0} },{ start: { hour: 13, minute: 30}, end: { hour: 14, minute: 0} } ] } ]

console.log('Now'.padEnd(10, ' '), 'Unavailable'.padEnd(32, ' '), 'Next Slot');
for(let input of inputs) {
    console.log(formatTime(input.now).padEnd(10, ' '), input.unavailable.map(formatSpan).join(', ').padEnd(32, ' '), formatTime(getFirstAvailableTime(input.now, input.unavailable)))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: worked like magic, thanks...but could u please explain to me the logic behind ```const start = Math.ceil((minutes(now) + 1) / timeSlotSize) * timeSlotSize;``` ?

Comment: Sure - we are setting start to the next available timeslot by rounding up to the nearest timeSlotSize minutes. So if the timeSlotSize is 30 and now is 11:00, then we'll set start to 11:30.